# How can I deploy my website to One.com from CircleCI via GitHub? Are there any integrations I need?

Tags: circleci

I've been looking to deploy my website which is stored on one.com and i've got a version now on GitHub, I was thinking of using CircleCI to deploy it as I use that to run cypress tests that are ran after I push to my GitHub repo.

I am just unsure where to begin on this and initial searches have come to a dead end.

So far I have:

1. Website deployed to one.com
2. GitHub repo with website code
3. CircleCI can see the repo

I just need to plug it all together but unsure how, any advice is appreciated.

Thanks,